# What is an MM Word™?

Tags: word, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a Word/Phrase™ series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of Phrase™ and Word™ puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an MM Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| MM Words™ | Not MM Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| DORY | MARLIN |
| EYES | EARS |
| FLAY | SKIN |
| RACY | ADULT |
| SPICY | SWEET |
| YELP | CRY |
| YIN | KARMA |

These are just some examples of MM Words and there are probably more.

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
MM Words™, Not MM Words™
DORY, MARLIN
EYES, EARS
FLAY, SKIN
RACY, ADULT
SPICY, SWEET
YELP, CRY
YIN, KARMA
```

Comment: At the moment, with the list of examples provided there's a rather basic rot13(pbagnvaf n L naq ng yrnfg bar NRVBH ibjry) rule going on. Are you able to add further examples which do not follow this seemingly trivial rule, or is that impossible by construction?

Comment: I mean, if you can tie that rule to why OP has called it an ‘MM word’, then you might have your answer. If you can’t, you likely don’t have your answer!

Comment: @ElGuest Indeed. I just can't see past that letter at the moment and would like to know if it's by design or just total coincidence!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An MM word is

> one that contains a Y that can be replaced by a K to form a new word.

This is because

> "MM" means "2000", and the transformation here is "[Y-2-K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)".

Comment: Gah, I see it now!